# Apache ReWrite Rules .HTACCESS FILE

Tags: linux, apache, wiki

Not really sure if I'm doing this properly.

I have a MediaWiki installed on Apache. Everything works fine, but I need to Rewrite URLs to make them shorter. Default path is http://mediawiki.my.domain/mediawiki/index.php/article, and I'm just trying to get them like this: http://mediawiki.my.domain/mediawiki/article

I edited **LocalSettings.php** on **MediaWiki** path with:

```
 $wgScriptPath = "/mediawiki";
 $wgScriptExtension = ".php";
 $wgArticlePath = "{$wgScriptPath}/wiki/$1";
 $wgUsePathInfo = true
```

And I also have and **.htaccess** file on /var/www/html with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?mediawiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
```

Whenever I go to **http://mediawiki.my.domain/mediawiki** I get a blank page. I am suspecting this is related to the **.htaccess** file and not the media wiki itself.

Any guidance you can provide me with?

Comment: I would have a look at this [example](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/wiki/Page_Title_--_.htaccess). But it seems to me that `$wgArticlePath` should look like this for you: `$wgArticlePath = "/mediawiki/$1";`

Comment: Hey, I replaced that and it still does not work.
According to the example, do you think I should replace "wiki" with "mediawiki" as it is my directory?

Comment: Update: Used this on Local Settings: 

$wgScriptPath = "/mediawiki";
$wgArticlePath = "/mediawiki/$1";

And used this on .htaccess

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^mediawiki/(.*)$ w/index.php?title=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^mediawiki/*$ w/index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^mediawiki$ w/index.php [L,QSA]

It is now redirecting ok, but stating MainPage is not found on directory

Comment: What is the name of the **directory** where the wiki is installed on your server ? Is it `mediawiki` or `w` or something else ? The .htaccess and the php config file don't seem to match. The [manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgScriptPath) says the default is `'/wiki'` for `$wgScriptPath`. Then it seems to me that you should change the `w` in your .htaccess to whatever the name of the directory is.

Comment: I did change wiki and w to "mediawiki" where my wiki is installed on LocalSettings and also .htaccess. 

So when I access my server at http://mediawiki.my.domain/mediawiki I get The requested URL /mediawiki/Main_Page was not found on this server.
So it looks like URLs are being rewritten but the server does not find content...

Comment: htaccess had to be on root path not mediawiki! That was it!